# CoreData and UITableViewController Problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, core-data

I have a app that works with Core Data. The data has a field with a date and I would like to show every entry of a month in a seperate section.

How do I actually get the data ?  I use a NSFetchedResultsController to get the data and use this :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[_fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];

}
```

to get the rows and this :

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
MyInfoObject *info = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

to get my actually data object.

Thanks

Comment: Can you add the code for how you set up your fetched results controller? This is where the sections are set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you set the sectionNameKeyPath when instantiating your fetchedResultsController

```
NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateKey" cacheName:@"Root"];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me a section for every date. What I want is just the month, any idea I can accomplish that ?

Comment: I would add another attribute, probably call it month_year ... and reference the document here ... http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW13

Comment: Create a custom managed object class, which is what I usually do ... and create a custom getter and setter similar to the way its done in Listing 2 and Listing 3. 

In the setter I would transform the date object into a string "MMYYYY", and in the getter I would check for the value, and if it doesn't exist, try return the same format of date that you used in the getter.

Comment: After you implement those getters and setters and they work, change the sectionNameKeyPath:@"dateKey" to your new month_year key.